# Firebase Website deployment

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm having trouble hosting my website on firebase.  My files, including index.html, have been uploaded onto firebase.

When I type in the URL given by firebase I get a 404 error.  However, if I type my URL and add '/index' at the end it works.

Any advice on how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're missing a rewrite in your `firebase.json` file.

```
"hosting": {
  // Add the "rewrites" section within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

For more on the configuration options see the [Firebase hosting documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites).